# Linear Algebra Principal Component Analysis Optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, machine-learning

I'm currently working my way through a textbook showing the derivation for principal component analysis algorithm. However, right at the end of the section, when we get the equation:

> = $\underset{d}{\operatorname{arg max}}$ Tr(**d**$^T$**X**$^T$**Xd**) subject to d$^T$d = $1$.

It follows with:

> This optimization problem may be solved using eigendecomposition. Specifically, the optimal **d** is given by the eigenvector of **X**$^T$**X** corresponding to the largest eigenvalue.

I don't follow why this is the case.

In case the matrix size matters here, **X** is an m by n matrix, and **d** is an n dimensional vector.

Comment: It's a standard exercise to use the method of Lagrange multipliers to solve the optimization problem and show that any eigenvector corresponding to an eigenvalue with the largest value is an optimal solution (there may be more than one optimal solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given, one can write the lagrangian for the optimization problem as

$$
\mathcal{L}(d, \lambda) = d^TX^TXd + \lambda(d^Td - 1)
$$

by the usual KKT conditions (which are necessary, but not sufficient), we know that we must have $\nabla \mathcal{L} = 0$, that is

$$
\nabla \mathcal{L} = \nabla(d^TX^TXd + \lambda(d^Td - 1)) = 2X^TXd +2\lambda d = 0
$$
or that
$$
X^TXd = - \lambda d = \lambda' d
$$
which is the usual eigenvalue equation (where $\lambda' = -\lambda$ is defined for convenience). The fact that the largest such $\lambda'$ maximizes the original optimization problem is left as an exercise for the reader!

---

A second, more elementary and enlightening proof not relying on KKT, is the following.

Note that $X^TX$ is positive semi-definite, hence the eigenvectors are (or, if singular, can be made) orthogonal and span the space. This means that, for any unit vector $v$ we have, where $X^TXu_i = \lambda_i u_i$ and $u_i^2 = 1$

$$
v = \sum_i v^i u_i
$$

and $\sum_i(v^i)^2 = 1$, where $v^i = u_i^Tv$. The idea here is then to express the $v$ in the basis of eigenvectors of $X^TX$ which preserves the orthogonality of the basis and scales it by $\text{diag}(\lambda_i)$ such that the final result is separable over the $v^i$ ($v$ expressed over the new basis) and makes it clear that we'd like to pick the largest eigenvector available.

Now, plugging this in to the original expression gives

$$
\begin{align}
v^TX^TX v &= \left(\sum_i v^i u_i\right)^TX^TX\left(\sum_j v^j u_j\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_i v^i u_i\right)^T\left(\sum_j v^j X^TX u_j\right)\\
&= \left(\sum_i v^i u_i\right)^T\left(\sum_j \lambda_j v^j u_j\right) \\
&= \sum_{ij} v^i v^j \lambda_j u_i^Tv_j
\end{align}
$$

but since all $u_i$ are orthogonal and have unit length, all cross-terms cancel and $u_i^2 = 1$, thus

$$
\sum_{ij} v^i v^j \lambda_j u_i^Tv_j = \sum_i (v^i)^2\lambda_i = v^TX^TX v.
$$

This objective is clearly separable over the $v^i$, so it's maximized when we make the term containing the greatest $\lambda_i$ the maximal term. Of course, note that the constraint is non-linear so this requires a (relatively simple) proof which I leave for the reader.

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question! Sorry that I can't upvote this, since I don't yet have the reputation needed to do that.

Comment: I might have missed something, but aren't KKT conditions necessary **only when** a [constraint qualification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Regularity_conditions_(or_constraint_qualifications)) holds? In this case, is the constraint qualification obvious or we should have proven that (for example) LICQ holds?

Answer (score 1):

Without invoking KKT or Lagrangian Multipliers, you could simply recast the problem to an unconstrained form and solve it.

Consider a vector $y$ of length $\gamma={\sqrt {y^Ty}}\,\,\,$ and note how varying the vector affects its length
$$\eqalign{
 \gamma^2 &= y^Ty \cr
\gamma\,d\gamma &= y^T\,dy \cr
d\gamma &= \gamma^{-1}y^T\,dy \cr
}$$
It's easy to construct a normalized vector: $\,\,\,n=\gamma^{-1}y$

In order to write the objective function a bit more succinctly, let $w=Xy$

Find the differential and gradient of the objective function
$$\eqalign{
 \lambda &= \gamma^{-2}\,w^Tw \cr
d\lambda
 &= 2\gamma^{-2}w^T\,dw - 2\gamma^{-3}w^Tw\,d\gamma \cr
 &= 2\gamma^{-2}w^T\,dw - 2\lambda\gamma^{-1}\,d\gamma \cr
 &= 2\gamma^{-2}y^TX^TX\,dy - 2\lambda\gamma^{-2}\,y^T\,dy \cr
 &= 2\gamma^{-2}\Big(X^TXy - \lambda y\Big)^T\,dy \cr
\frac{\partial\lambda}{\partial y} &= 2\gamma^{-2} (X^TXy - \lambda y) \cr
}$$
Setting the gradient to zero leaves you with an eigenvalue equation, which you can write in terms of either the normalized or denormalized vector
$$\eqalign{
X^TX\,y = \lambda y \cr
X^TX\,n = \lambda n \cr
}$$