# An inductive proof on Principal Component Analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, induction

I am having trouble with proof left as an exercise to the reading in the Deep Learning Book (https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/linear_algebra.html) in section 2.12 on principal component analysis. I can see why the eigenvectors with the largest eigenvalues must compose $\boldsymbol{D}$ but I cannot compose the inductive part of the proof. I can almost prove it for the simple case where the vector taken is certainly the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue

The first step in this proof starts with what is shown at the end of the chapter for $\boldsymbol{d}^*$ (which is a one-dimensional version of $\boldsymbol{D}$). Towards the end, we reach the statement
$$\underset{\boldsymbol{d}}{arg\,max}\,(\boldsymbol{d}^T\boldsymbol{X}^T\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{d})$$ which is subject to $\boldsymbol{d}^T \boldsymbol{d} = 1$. This I decomposed into
$$\underset{\boldsymbol{d}}{arg\,max}\,((\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{d})^T (\boldsymbol{X}\boldsymbol{d}))$$
which then I decomposed into its eigenvectors
$$\underset{\boldsymbol{d}}{arg\,max}\,((\alpha_1 \lambda_1 \boldsymbol
{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_k \lambda_k \boldsymbol{v}_k)^T (\alpha_1 \lambda_1 \boldsymbol
{v}_1 + \dots + \alpha_k \lambda_k \boldsymbol{v}_k))$$
Where $\boldsymbol{v_i}$ corresponds to the i-th eigenvalue. After which turns into something I'm not so sure about (I don't know if what's next will be useful for me of if its correct).

This question (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2404189/939384) provides a similar answer (and the second part contains the direction I was going in) however it also leaves the inductive proof that I am looking for as an exercise to the reader.

Appreciate any guidance possible, especially guidance on the inductive step after this single part is complete.

Comment: Instead of using the eigenvectors of $X$, use the eigenvectors of  $X^TX$. In particular, the spectral theorem says that $X^TX$ has a complete set of orthonormal eigenvectors. Now, expand $d^T(X^TX)d$ after writing $d$ as a linear combination of these eigenvectors.

Comment: Ok thank you, I see where you are going with that. My only question is where is induction coming in?

Comment: Nothing inductive about this proof. Perhaps we can inductively extend the result from just $\mathbf d$ to $\mathbf D$.